# Changes made to XSLTListViewWebPart in SharePoint Designer not showing on page

Tags: sharepoint-designer, xslt-list-view-web-part

I am trying to learn, through trial and error, how to get values from parameters that are declared in the ParameterBindings section in an XSLTListViewWebPart through SharePoint Designer.

I have noticed that occasionally, when I make a change to the web part that I am guessing is not well formed, I see no change to the SharePoint page when I refresh the browser.

What I am wondering is where could I see the error message associated with my ill-formed XSLT?

In SharePoint designer I don't see an Errors or Output window that would show the progress as my saved changes to the web part get published to my site.  I also tried looking at my machine's Event Viewer and couldn't find any errors associated with my publishes.  Finally, I looked at the ULS logs while I was publishing and while I was requesting the changed page and I don't see any errors coming through at those times.

What is the best approach to track errors when publishing from SharePoint Designer?

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint Designer will inform you about ill-formed XSLT. It will pop up an error message, albeit sometimes cryptic.

But, SharePoint Designer has the bad habit to revert to the original xslt in some situations. When you save and close the page in SPD, then open it again, are your changes still there?

If you have customised the XSLT and these changes don't stick, edit the XSLT and find all instances of `ddwrt:ghost=hide` in any tag. Remove all of these and apply your changes again.

Comment: When I am trying new changes in SPD I change some plain text on the page.  The change to the plain text does not show when I refresh.  I will try removing the ghost attribute.  Thank you.